# Changing size in image_submit_tag

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Is it possible to change size in image_submit_tag? Just `<%= image_submit_tag ('search.png', size: "40x40")%>` doesn't work for me. Thanks ahead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Give it a css class and do it with CSS.

For example:

```
<%= image_submit_tag('search.png', class: "search-img")%>

.search-img {
width: 20px;
height: 20px;
}
```

Or specify the html width and height options:

```
<%= image_submit_tag('search.png', width: "20", height: "20")%>
```